# gamm() function failing in JRI

Tags: java, r, jri

I have installed JRI to run with NetBeans 7.4 using 32-bit R 3.0.2 and Java jdk1.7.0_45, on Windows 7.

I am using the following Java code

```
     REXP load=re.eval("source('C:\\\\SearchPath\\\\gammaDistAnova.r')");
     String errStr=load.asString();
     REXP stats=re.eval("gammaDistAnova.getStats(ref, target)");
```

to call the following R script.

```
gammaDistAnova.getStats<-function(ref, target){
  library("MASS") # Library containing fitdistr
  library("mgcv")
  library("stats")

  # Get mean and SD of reference
  gr=fitdistr(ref+0.00001,"gamma")  # Ref is a vector of (reference) values.  The     0.00001 is to prevent errors due to zero values
  meanRef<-gr[1]$estimate['shape']/gr[1]$estimate['rate']  # Mean of ref vector  
  SDref<-sqrt(gr[1]$estimate['shape']/(gr[1]$estimate['rate']^2)) # SD of ref vector

  # Get mean and SD of target
  gt=fitdistr(target+0.00001,"gamma")  # target is a vector of (target) values.  The 0.00001 is to prevent errors due to zero values
  meanTarget<-gt[1]$estimate['shape']/gt[1]$estimate['rate']  # Mean of target vector  
  SDTarget<-sqrt(gt[1]$estimate['shape']/(gt[1]$estimate['rate']^2)) # SD of target vector

  # Analysis of variance between the distributions
  n=300
  x=rgamma(n, shape=gr[1]$estimate['shape'], scale=1/gr[1]$estimate['rate'])
  y=rgamma(n, shape=gt[1]$estimate['shape'], scale=1/gt[1]$estimate['rate'])
  random1 <- sample(c("level1","level2","level3"), n, replace=TRUE)
  debug=list(random1 = ~1)
#  glmm1 <- gamm(y ~ x, random=list(random1 = ~1))
#  anova(glmm1$gam)

  out=list("refMean"=meanRef, "refSD"=SDref, "targetMean"=meanTarget, "targetSD"=SDTarget, "lx"=length(x), "ly"=length(y))
  out
}
```

Everything runs fine (everything returned in the list seems valid and what I would expect) until I uncomment

```
glmm1 <- gamm(y ~ x, random=list(random1 = ~1))
```

in which case the function returns null, indicating a failure.

While the function fails with JRI, it runs without any problems on RStudio Version 0.98.501.

Edit:

I tried

```
  glmm1 <- gamm(y ~ x, random=list(random1 = ~1))
  errStr=geterrmessage()
  errStr
```

but

```
 re.eval("gammaDistAnova.getStats(ref, target)");
```

still returned null

Comment: Did it work? if not ill try to run this code in my machine.

Answer (score 1):

You should check in your "lib" directory in `....\R\win-library\3.0.2`

and check if you can obrerve the `mgcv` package, if not, downloaded it again into your R used version

One option is that you downloaded this library into an earlier version of R.

Comment: I don't have that directory but do have ..\R\R-3.0.2\library\mgcv.  The files therein are dated Sept. 9, 2013 and the subdirectories are dated 16 Dec. 2013 (the date I stalled R).  Thanks,

Comment: When you ran the r code (using only R) was it through " source" ? Or as is in the console?

Comment: Yes.  It was through source.  I have noticed that the gam() function works fine through JRI but gamm() does not.  Thanks,

Comment: can you add a data set sample using `dput(data)` so i could run your cone on my machine?